# pandas series,isnull() is not working inside list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, null, list-comprehension

for the following simple code:

```
drop_cols = [col for col in train.columns if col[0] == 'V' and train[col].isnulll().sum()/len(train) > 0.76]
drop_cols
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 drop_cols = [col for col in train.columns if col[0] == 'V' and train[col].isnulll().sum()/len(train) > 0.76]
>         2 drop_cols
>
> in (.0)
>   ----> 1 drop_cols = [col for col in train.columns if col[0] == 'V' and train[col].isnulll().sum()/len(train) > 0.76]
>         2 drop_cols
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
>   **getattr**(self, name)    5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):    5066
>   return self[name]
>   -> 5067             return object.**getattribute**(self, name)    5068     5069     def **setattr**(self, name, value):
>
> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isnulll'

isnull() is working elsewhere. What is the cause and fix for this?

Comment: Your error message includes the typo: `isnulll` has 3 lowercase L's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have more than 50 rep points to add a comment so need to reply here.

You just have a typo in a code `train[col].isnulll().sum()/len(train)` (triple lll)

```py
drop_cols = [col for col in train.columns if col[0] == 'V' and train[col].isnull().sum()/len(train) > 0.76]
```